# How do you use the future of the verb devoir when using another verb aswell?

Tags: temps-grammatical

"There is a dress code, so I have to wear a kilt"

I know this sentence makes sense in English but would I need to change the tense for it to make sense in French? For example:

"There is going to be a dress code, so I will have to wear a kilt"
(considering I have said the event is going to happen next year)

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Il y aura un dress-code, je devrai porter un kilt.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the present for a future event in French in about the same circumstances where you can do it in English. You need a future tense to refer to a specific future event, but if you're talking about an event that could potentially recur, then you can refer to it in an “intemporal” way in the present tense.

> There is a dress code, so I have to wear a kilt.
> There is/will be a dress code, so I will have to wear a kilt.
>
> Il y a un code vestimentaire, donc je dois mettre un kilt.
> Il y a/aura un code vestimentaire, donc je devrai mettre un kilt.
> Il y a un code vestimentaire, donc il faut que je mette un kilt.
> Il y a/aura un code vestimentaire, donc il faudra que je mette un kilt.